# Fetch details of VM instance in Azure using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-.net

I need to fetch details of **VM instance** in Azure using the **Azure SDK APIs'**.
These details include various parameters like...
* Host Name
* IP address
* Instance Name
* Location
* Tag name etc.

There are two types of VMs' in Azure...
* **Classic VM** (through the older portal)
* **VM** (using the new portal)

The classic VM used to have a cloud service created with the same name.
I was able  to get the above mentioned parameter details for the classic VM using the **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute** library and the **HostedService** class.

Code Snippet:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PFXCertificatePath, Constants.CertificatePassword);
var cred = new CertificateCloudCredentials(Constants.SubscriptionID, cert);
var computeClient = CloudContext.Clients.CreateComputeManagementClient(cred);
List<HostedServiceListResponse.HostedService> hostedServiceOperations =                                    computeClient.HostedServices.List().HostedServices.ToList<HostedServiceListResponse.HostedService>();
foreach (HostedServiceListResponse.HostedService hostedService in hostedServiceOperations)
{
    HostedServiceGetDetailedResponse detailedResponse = computeClient.HostedServices.GetDetailed(hostedService.ServiceName);
    List<HostedServiceGetDetailedResponse.Deployment> deployments = detailedResponse.Deployments.
                                                                    ToList<HostedServiceGetDetailedResponse.Deployment>();

    foreach (HostedServiceGetDetailedResponse.Deployment deployment in deployments)
    {
        List<RoleInstance> roleInstances = deployment.RoleInstances.ToList<RoleInstance>();
        foreach (RoleInstance roleInstance in roleInstances)
        {
            string privateId = deployment.PrivateId;
            Console.WriteLine($"Host Name: {roleInstance.HostName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Instance Name: {roleInstance.InstanceName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Instance size: {roleInstance.InstanceSize}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Private IP: {roleInstance.IPAddress}");
            foreach (RoleInstance.PublicIP publicIP in roleInstance.PublicIPs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Public IP: {publicIP.Address}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Role Name: {roleInstance.RoleName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Power state: {roleInstance.PowerState}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Instance status: {roleInstance.InstanceStatus}");
            foreach (InstanceEndpoint instanceEndpoint in roleInstance.InstanceEndpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Instance endpoint name: {instanceEndpoint.Name}, port: {instanceEndpoint.Port}, protocol: {instanceEndpoint.Protocol}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Instance Virtual IP address: {instanceEndpoint.VirtualIPAddress}, local port: {instanceEndpoint.LocalPort}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I've found that this approach does not work for the new VM (i.e. the one created from the new portal) as a cloud service is not created for it.
Using the new **ARM** library (**Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources**) I'm able to get basic information of this VM which is limited to Name and location information using the **GenericResource** class.

```
var token = GetAuthorizationHeader(Constants.TenantID);//Uses Active Directory authentication token
var tokenCred = new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(token);
ResourceManagementClient resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(tokenCred);
resourceClient.SubscriptionId = Constants.SubscriptionID;
var resourceGroups = resourceClient.ResourceGroups;
IResourcesOperations resources = resourceClient.Resources;
List<GenericResource> vmResources = resources.List().Where(r => r.Type == "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines").ToList<GenericResource>();
foreach (GenericResource resource in vmResources)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Resource Name: {resource.Name}, Resource Location: {resource.Location},Resource Plan: {resource.Plan}");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippets?

Comment: I've added the snippets @juvchan

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code to get instance information:

```
public static void GetVirtualMachine(TokenCredentials credential, string groupName, string vmName, string subscriptionId)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Getting information about the virtual machine...");

   var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential);
   computeManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
   var vmResult = computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.Get(groupName, vmName, "instanceview");

   Console.WriteLine("hardwareProfile");
   Console.WriteLine("   vmSize: " + vmResult.HardwareProfile.VmSize);
   Console.WriteLine("\nstorageProfile");
   Console.WriteLine("   imageReference");
   Console.WriteLine("       publisher: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Publisher);
   Console.WriteLine("       offer: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer);
   Console.WriteLine("       sku: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Sku);
   Console.WriteLine("       version: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Version);
   Console.WriteLine("   osDisk");
   Console.WriteLine("       osType: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType);
   Console.WriteLine("       name: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("       createOption: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.OsDisk.CreateOption);
   Console.WriteLine("       uri: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri);
   Console.WriteLine("       caching: " + vmResult.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Caching);
   Console.WriteLine("\nosProfile");
   Console.WriteLine("   computerName: " + vmResult.OsProfile.ComputerName);
   Console.WriteLine("   adminUsername: " + vmResult.OsProfile.AdminUsername);
   Console.WriteLine("   provisionVMAgent: " + vmResult.OsProfile.WindowsConfiguration.ProvisionVMAgent.Value);
   Console.WriteLine("   enableAutomaticUpdates: " + vmResult.OsProfile.WindowsConfiguration.EnableAutomaticUpdates.Value);
   Console.WriteLine("\nnetworkProfile");
   foreach (NetworkInterfaceReference nic in vmResult.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("    networkInterface id: " + nic.Id);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("\nvmAgent");
   Console.WriteLine("    vmAgentVersion" + vmResult.InstanceView.VmAgent.VmAgentVersion);
   Console.WriteLine("    statuses");
   foreach (InstanceViewStatus stat in vmResult.InstanceView.VmAgent.Statuses)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("        code: " + stat.Code);
      Console.WriteLine("        level: " + stat.Level);
      Console.WriteLine("        displayStatus: " + stat.DisplayStatus);
      Console.WriteLine("        message: " + stat.Message);
      Console.WriteLine("        time: " + stat.Time);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("\ndisks");
   foreach (DiskInstanceView idisk in vmResult.InstanceView.Disks)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("    name: " + idisk.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("    statuses");
      foreach (InstanceViewStatus istat in idisk.Statuses)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("        code: " + istat.Code);
         Console.WriteLine("        level: " + istat.Level);
         Console.WriteLine("        displayStatus: " + istat.DisplayStatus);
         Console.WriteLine("        time: " + istat.Time);
      }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("\nVM general status");
   Console.WriteLine("   provisioningStatus: " + vmResult.ProvisioningState);
   Console.WriteLine("   id: " + vmResult.Id);
   Console.WriteLine("   name: " + vmResult.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("   type: " + vmResult.Type);
   Console.WriteLine("   location: " + vmResult.Location);
   Console.WriteLine("\nVM instance status");
   foreach (InstanceViewStatus istat in vmResult.InstanceView.Statuses)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\n   code: " + istat.Code);
      Console.WriteLine("   level: " + istat.Level);
      Console.WriteLine("   displayStatus: " + istat.DisplayStatus);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Which version of the Azure Compute Management library (SDK) are you using ? I'm using the latest stable version 12.6.0  I did not find the Properties HardwareProfile, StorageProfile etc. on the VirtualMachineGetResponse class.

Comment: @sundeep You need to enable pre-releases in Nuget to get the latest, that supports this. At the time of writing this, the version is 14.x preview